# SQLDeveloper doesn't shows any data when opening a table data via UI

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have being struggling with some problems with sql developer recently. I have a local database and when I try to see specific table´s data using the command: `SELECT * FROM <tablename>` I have no problem and the command shows correctly all the data that the table got inside.

But when I try to see the data from the graphical interface of SQL developer, using"Connections -> Tables -> right-click on [table] -> Open", I can open and see all tabs except the"Data" tab. I have no error message so I can not figure it out what could be.

This is what I got:

[image: the tables are shown and I have no problem]

Comment: Hello, you have tried to turn off and back on the SQLDEVELOPER tool ?

Comment: Hi! I have restart the database, I have change my VPN, I have turned of and turned the sql developer back and still doesn't work. The most rare thing, is that I have no error message, so Idk how can I handle this.

Comment: What is your version of SQL Developer and what is that ICON third on the left top corner  ? First is add conneciton, second is refresh and third one is ?

Comment: Also, what os age and jdk? Any errors on the log panel?

Answer (score 0):

Is old but for future reference: for me the problem was missing select grants on table.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).